# Elixir integer list to string causes (UnicodeConversionError) invalid code point

Tags: string-interpolation, elixir

## **The problem**

I need to create a string interpolating a list of integers in it.

```
"""
SomeQuery {
  someQuery(articleIds: #{inspect article_ids}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
"""
```

## **Failing example**

For example, the list `[725553234]` makes the example above to fail:

```
article_ids = [725553234]

"""
SomeQuery {
  someQuery(articleIds: #{article_ids}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
"""
```

> ```
> ** (exit) an exception was raised:
>     ** (UnicodeConversionError) invalid code point 725553234
>         (elixir) lib/list.ex:839: List.to_string/1
>         (commsapp_api) lib/my_project/client.ex:70: CommsappApi.News.Clients.CommunicationMs.Client.articles_feed/3
> ```

## **System**

> Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10]
>   [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
>
> Elixir 1.6.3 (compiled with OTP 20)

## **Tried solutions**

It tried the following:

- Using `inspect` is not working: `articleIds: #{inspect(article_ids)}`
- Using the IO.inspect with the `:char_lists` opt with `:as_list`: `IO.inspect(article_ids, char_lists: :as_lists`
- Trying to join the integer list as string with: `articleIds: [#{Enum.join(article_ids, ", ")}]`
- Interpolating the integers parsed to string with: `Enum.map(article_ids, &Integer.to_string/1) |> Enum.join(", ")`
- I tried using a single line instead of a multiline string, not working
- Many things I don't remember after trying different solutions... >.<

## **Guesses**

**The problem comes when using the brackets in the string**, Elixir treats the interporlation as a list and raises the error because it cannot find the codepoints.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the exact output you want? And none of those things you tried worked?

Comment: `#{inspect(ids)}` would probably work.

Comment: @mudasobwa nope, it doesn’t

Comment: @Dogbert none of them (and others more) didn’t work. I need to have the strong representation with the integer list to be able to make a network call using that string as a body (not using a network library in my code JFYI, it’s a third party dep the one which uses httpoison).

Comment: In my `iex` it does btw. Try `ids=[725553234], """\n#{inspect ids}\n"""` and you’ll see yourself.

Comment: @mudasobwa try to interpolate the list within brackets. Anyway, I made something’s work in iex that didn’t work in real code (which is bizarre)

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Do you want a list?—inspect a list. Do you want an integer?—just get rid of brackets.

Comment: @mudasobwa For this use case is mandatory a string (the multi line example string) with a list of integers (the id list) inside brackets. You cannot interpolate am inspect in the example I gave, it’s going to raise the code point exception.

Comment: Are you using `inspect` or `IO.inspect`? @mudasobwa is talking about `inspect` which should work inside interpolation.

Comment: @Dogbert inspect is not working either, it's raising the same exception

Comment: @qgadrian `inspect` always returns a string so you can't get the same exception. Are you absolutely sure about that?

Comment: @Dogbert I just tried it again and still the same error. I know it’s weird, could you try to just assign the example to a variable and tell me I didn’t loose my mind?

Comment: @qgadrian Given that you're confident of this behavior and two smart folks like dogbert and mudasobwa can't repro the problem, maybe you should add some details (version of Elixir, version of Erlang, exact code you're trying etc.).  Just a suggestion.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci yeah, fair point. I just updated the question!

Comment: You might also share OS and encoding as they may also have bearing on reproducing the behavior.

Comment: Is client.ex:70 indeed points to this string interpolation?

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeap

Comment: Also, please confirm that `article_ids = [725553234]` followed by string with interpolation assignment fails in `iex`. Not deeply in the project code, just this: assign ids ⇒ assign interpolated string ⇒ boom.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation on [strings, binaries and charlists](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html), the charlists are defined as a list of point codes, i.e. integers. The code

```
article_ids = [725553234]
"#{article_ids}"
```

attempts to print the character which point code is `725553234`. This point code is not defined and you get the error. Replace  `725553234` by `65` and you should get an `A` character.

To interpolate your list of integers, you may want to do things like this:

```
iex(5)> a=[65, 66, 67]
'ABC'
iex(6)> "#{Enum.map(a, fn(c) -> Integer.to_string(c)<>" " end)}"
"65 66 67 "
```

BTW, if you look at list `[65, 66, 67]` is interpreted as `'ABC'`.

Answer (score 0):

By using Enum.join return string and separate integer by ","

```
Enum.join(list, ",")
```

or using Enum.map return as list by changing every integer value to string

```
Enum.map(list, &Integer.to_string/1)
```

list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
Enum.join(list, ",") -> "1,2,3,4"

Enum.map(list, &Integer.to_string/1) -> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```